# ERROR Android app not installed on device?

Tags: android

I have made a Android app and when I finished it and tested it through eclipse and Android SDK it works fine.. But when I test it on my android phone and install it with an app called AppInstaller and run it then it says "app not installed on device".. WTF? How is that possible when its in the menu and I can tap on it?

This is my code. (And yes I did X out the website on purpose)

MANIFEST.XML:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="XXXXXXX"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/new_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET"
    android:description="@string/app_description">

    <activity
        android:name="XXXXX"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Maybe your phone sdkVersion < 10 ?

Comment: You should not need any special app to install APKs. You can download and install APKs from the browser, for instance.

Comment: Its not online yet.. The app is on my conputer and I put it on my phone and go into the installer app and install the APK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"app not installed on device" is a message I've gotten when the SD card is mounted (and unavailable), or when trying to tap a shortcut on the desktop to an app that's been removed in some way.  If this is the problem I'd guess your case would be the former.

Comment: I tried reinstalling the app and then I waited 5 minutes and tried it again and it still says the same thing :(

Answer (score 0):

Either your phone Api version is less than 10.
i.e. below OS 2.3

or, 
if you have previously installed same application on that phone. 
Try uninstalling that before installing new one.

Comment: My OS is 2.3.4.... also I have tested this same app before on this same phone and it worked

Comment: have you uninstalled this same app from your app this time..before installing new one..

Comment: I have uninsalled and deleted the app every time I tried a new version, so yes lol :)

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had this problem with an app that I was writing to experiment with widgets.

The problem that I had turned out to be that I had exported the app unsigned, which has worked previously.  It seems that you can't install an unsigned app that contains a widget.  Signing the app when exporting it allowed it to be installed ok.

Answer (score 0):

You've set the following permission twice:

```
android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

Getting rid of one of them should clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure You're using Java 6, as Java 7 builded packages are at least problematic.